# deviceRegistryEnrich: unable to enrich from registry error because thingName found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-analytics

AWS IOT Analytics Pipeline is unable to enrich data from device registry or device shadow because it cannot find the metadata of the thing and the shadow details in the message. **How is these data brought into the message for enrichment?**  Is there some kind of setting or I have to explicitly fetch these details and include in the message?

I've configured the IOT Analytics channel to get messages from $aws/things/+/shadow/update/documents.

Query for the action:
SELECT topic() as topic, * AS message FROM "$aws/things/+/shadow/update/documents"

Channel configured from Action in IOT Core.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add Device Shadow and Device Registry data to your messages by leveraging the corresponding Pipeline Activities.

Your messages will first be placed in your Channel (without the Device Shadow and/or Device Registry data). If you Pipeline is defined with the DeviceRegistryEnrich Activity and/or the DeviceShadowEnrich Activity, when it executes, it will send to your Data Store a copy of your messages with the relevant data added.

The [Pipeline Activities documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/pipeline-activities.html) includes examples of how a message would look like before (ie: in your Channel) and after (ie: in your Data Store) Pipeline processing for the [DeviceRegistryEnrich Activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/pipeline-activities.html#aws-iot-analytics-pipeline-activities-deviceregistryenrich) and the [DeviceShadowEnrich Activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/pipeline-activities.html#aws-iot-analytics-pipeline-activities-deviceshadowenrich).

If you are creating your IoT-Analytics Channel through the IoT-Core console (ie: IoT > Act > Create Rule > and select an Action to 'Send a message to an IoT Analytics Channel'), the console will create a Channel to deliver your messages to, but no associated Pipeline and Data Store.

To create and manage Pipelines and Data Stores you can use the IoT-Analytics console (see [AWS IoT Analytics Console Quickstart Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) ), or the CLI commands (see [Getting Started with AWS IoT Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) ).